# Difference between keyset and cursor paginations?

Tags: pagination

I am reading several resources about API pagination. I still do not get the difference between keyset and cursor pagination. How are they different?
Resource example: https://medium.com/swlh/paginating-requests-in-apis-d4883d4c1c4c

Answer (score 1):

I read the same article and I think it's wrong. There is no difference between keyset, cursor, and seek method. They refer to the same strategy which is to use a unique identifier to select a limited subset of rows in a database below or above the row at which that identifier is making reference to return "pages" in the API

Answer (score 0):

They are almost the same with a slight difference. Cursor pagination is better for maintaining a consistent position and handling real-time updates in dynamic applications given that provides a straightforward way to achive it, on the other hand Keyset pagination can achive the same buy it may require additional effort when dealing with real-time updates, so the choice depends on the requirements of your application.